# Converting Unix timestamp to Date Time String

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a unix timestamp  (something like this 1537364040000) into a Date:Time **String**

for this, I did something like this

```
this.selectedTime  = new Date(this.selectedTime*1000);
```

*(My this.selectedTime before this was a unix timestamp)*

This should console.log something like this

```
console.log(this.selectedTime) //Tue May 24 50687 17:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(typeof this.selectedTime) //Object
```

In the above, The typeof happens to be an object and I wanted it be string so I did this

```
this.selectedTime = JSON.stringify(this.selectedTime)
```

which is console.logging something like this

```
console.log(this.selectedTime)
"+050687-06-10T20:40:00.000Z"
```

**[Question:]** Can someone help me in figuring out how can we get something like this **Tue May 24 50687 17:30:00 GMT+0530** or this
**Tue May 24 50687 17:30:00** as a string?

**[Question Update:]**: Also can someone help in figuring out what it is logging say **50687** instead of proper year (Tue May 24 **50687** 17:30:00)

I am using coincap history API http://coincap.io/history/1day/BTC

Comment: `typeof this.selectedTime.toString()`?

Comment: @ChrisSharp I appended the word *string* into it this question

Comment: Whats a datetime string? What you want is a datetime object and then you might want to render this in a certain way. There is no such thing as a datetime string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the date object to string at time of creation:

```js
this.selectedTime = 1537364040000;
this.selectedTime  = new Date(this.selectedTime*1000).toString();
console.log(this.selectedTime)
```

If you don't want the year **50687** then lose the `*1000`

```js
this.selectedTime = 1537364040000;
this.selectedTime  = new Date(this.selectedTime).toString(); /* no multiplier */
console.log(this.selectedTime)
```

Comment: Updated the question. See if you can please answer that as well.

Comment: Lose the `*1000`

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

```
console.log(this.selectedTime.toString());
//"Fri Sep 21 2018 09:24:40 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)"

console.log(this.selectedTime.toDateString());
//"Fri Sep 21 2018"

console.log(this.selectedTime.toISOString());
//"2018-09-21T07:26:28.793Z"

console.log(this.selectedTime.toGMTString());
//"Fri, 21 Sep 2018 07:27:00 GMT"
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed an example of the output, and perhaps a little explanation as to why this would help.